What's the CRC Polynomial in EnDAT 2.2 protocol?
I am implementing an EnDAT2.2 readout in an FPGA. Can't find the CRC polynomial anywhere in the document. Is 5-bit CRC something so standard that it doesn't need to be mentioned?
https://www.heidenhain.us/addl-materials/enews/stories_1012/EnDat.pdf

There are only ten different five-bit CRCs. You can try all of them. But try those three first: https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/crc5.html

thank you. i have very limited ways of testing, would love to be more sure...

@Janka There's more than that. The CRC is initialized to some value, you feed in bits LSB first or MSB first, and then the bits are XORed with some final value (could be zero so it counts), so already 20 thousand combinations for only 10 polynomials.

According to this forum thread, the polynomial is 0x0B, and the init value is 0xFF.

I think the Protocol does not specify that Polynomial. Each maker (hardware & software) can chose it & then each user can configure it. You have to check the SPECS for the Model you are targeting.

@Justme and that's before we talk about my bugs

@Prem seems so, now i can't figure whos encoder i am using :/

@Velvet thank you, reading there. oh no, i can't read german. is there anything else interesting, or i will just try the values you found?

You are not alone with the Bugs ! https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000-microcontrollers-group/c2000/f/c2000-microcontrollers-forum/942597/tms320f28388d-how-to-use-vcu-library-to-generate-endat-crc

https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000-microcontrollers-group/c2000/f/c2000-microcontrollers-forum/717917/tms320f28379d-nonconsistent-crc-check-for-heidenhain-endat22-22bit-at1218-sensor

I would contact Heidenhain and ask them for the CRC poly and initial value

@TQQQ Run it through DeepL translate. It's really good for German,

@Justme in practice the pre-loaded value is either 0xff or 0x00 in most cases. But even 20000 different combinations can be played through automatically in a short time.
